# using UpdatePanel for asp.net tree view SelectedNodeChanged event

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, treeview, updatepanel

I have `TextBox` and `treeview` likes ,

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Width="150px" ReadOnly="true"
BorderStyle="Double">
</asp:TextBox>
</ContentTemplate>  
</asp:UpdatePanel>  

<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" ImageSet="Arrows"   
OnSelectedNodeChanged="TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged" >
<NodeStyle Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalPadding="5px"
NodeSpacing="0px" VerticalPadding="0px" />
<SelectedNodeStyle CssClass="treeHover"></SelectedNodeStyle>
</asp:TreeView>
```

Coding for `SelectedNodeChanged` event ,

```
protected void TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
    txtName.Text = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text;
}
```

My Update Panel doesn't work properly ,I want to know what's wrong in my code ?

Comment: r u geting any problem when u r putting in update panel

Comment: Have a look at the following: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @Amit Singh , I've edited my question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this....

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Width="150px" ReadOnly="true"
    BorderStyle="Double">
    </asp:TextBox>
    </ContentTemplate>  
     <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="TreeView1" EventName="SelectedNodeChanged" />
            </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>  

    <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" ImageSet="Arrows"   
    OnSelectedNodeChanged="TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged" >
    <NodeStyle Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalPadding="5px"
    NodeSpacing="0px" VerticalPadding="0px" />
    <SelectedNodeStyle CssClass="treeHover"></SelectedNodeStyle>
    </asp:TreeView>
```